# Motives of resolutions of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, resolution-of-singularities

Suppose $X'$ is a resolution of singularities of a projective variety $X$  over a field $k$ of characteristic 0 that is functorial for smooth morphisms.

How are the (mixed) motives of $X$ related to (pure) motives of $X'$?

If $X'$ and $X''$ are two resolutions of singularities of $X$, how are their motives related? What if $X'$ is a minimal resolution?

I suppose I am looking for properties of the functor on motives induced by resolution of singularities.

Comment: The cohomology of any resolution of $X$ includes the *intersection* cohomology of $X$ as a summand. So the motive of a resolution of $X$ should include the intersection cohomology motive of $X$ as a summand, and the motives of any two resolutions should have an interesting common summand. I don't know if these are theorems for a suitable notion of intersection cohomology motives.

Comment: Wildeshaus wrote some papers on so-called intersection motives. Yet one either has to assume that X belongs to certain "simple" families or to rely on really hard motivic conjectures.

Answer (score 1):

If $X'$ is a minimal resolution of $X$ then $X''$ can be obtained from it by means of successive blow ups of smooth subvarieties, right? Then $M(X')$ is a direct summand of $M(X'')$; for example, see Manin's "Correspondences, motifs and monoidal transformations".

Next, you can associate a complex of Chow motives $W(X)$ to $X$; see either "Descent, motives and K-theory" of H. Gillet and C. Soulé or my https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601713/. $W(X)$ is defined up to homotopy equivalence, and you can choose a representative in the corresponding class such that $M(X')$ (or $M(X'')$) is its degree zero term; note that $W(X)$ is concentrated in non-positive degrees if you use the homological convention for Chow motives. Respectively, the cohomology of $X$ and $X"$ contain the "pure part" of the cohomology of $X$ (you can read some more of my papers if you are interested in weight spectral sequences).

Comment: There are a few problems here. First, what you call "a minimal" in your answer (i.e., dominated by any other) should probably be called "the smallest", and it does not exist in general. Take, for instance, $X$ to be the cone over $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$, it has two minimal resolutions --- $X'$, which is a $\mathbb{P}^3$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$, and $X''$, which is a $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle over $\mathbb{P}^2$, related by a flip. Note, in particular, that their Chow motives are **different**. Therefore, it is not possible that each of them equals the degree zero term of $W(X)$.

Comment: Yes, I know that the smallest resolution of singularities does not have to exist in general.  So, my answer does not say anything in the case where the smallest resolution does not exist. Unfortunately. I know very little about the minimal model program; in particular, I cannot relate it to motives.

Comment: As about the degree zero term of $W(X)$: it depends on the choice of a representative in the corresponding homotopy equivalence class.
.